# AnyLogic travelling camera

Tags: camera, anylogic, presentation

I want my model to be displayed in a cool video, in which a camera goes through my model.

Is there any guide for smooth tracking shots and functions that can be used?
I could not find good information in the AnyLogic Library :(

Answer (score 0):

You can design any camera movement you like.

Simplest way is to create a custom agent with a camera at its origin and make the agent move around. Or add a camera to existing agents to "view over their shoulder".

Or check the example models with search term "camera".

Or make your camera positions dynamic:
[image]

You can do anything you want :)